# jQuery function not running on submission of validated form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, galleryview

I am using the jquery galleryview plugin and I have added the ability to pause the slideshow when a link is clicked (revealing a form) and then restarted when the close button is clicked.

This works fine (see below) but I would also like the slideshow to start when the form is submitted. I can do this by adding the submit button to the list of elements that restarts the slideshow, but if the form does not pass the validation, I don't want the slideshow to restart.

Here's my galleryview code (condensed):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.galleryView = function(options) {
    // Some code
        return this.each(function() {
        // Some more code
            $("#closeEnquiry").click(function(){
                restartGallery();
            });

            function restartGallery(e) {
                // Code to restart gallery
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my form submit/validate code (restartGallery function does not run):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enquiryForm").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            YourName: {
                required: true,
            },
            YourEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            YourName: "Please let us know who you are.",
            YourEmail: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you."
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            $.post('projectform.php', $("#enquiryForm").serialize(), function(data) {
                closePopup();
                $('#enquiryFormContainer').prepend(data);
                restartGallery();  // This does not run...
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas how I can run the restartGallery function from the validate function?

Comment: Can't you just call "restartGallery()" in the submit handler *before* calling `$.post()` ?

Comment: Maybe, you should stop standard form submitting?

Comment: @kirilloid what would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: @Pointy That restarts the slideshow, but everything after that then fails...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once where JQuery objects were becoming invalid (disposed) after changing the DOM through AJAX.

Therefore, my guess is that after doing `$('#enquiryFormContainer').prepend(data)`, some DOM objects (and their event handlers) referenced by `restartGallery()` are becoming invalid. For example, if `restartGallery()` references a variable that was initialized like this: `var myDiv = $("#myDiv")`, then you will need to re-initialize it after the AJAX call finishes.